# iOS UIPickerView - Appearance

Tags: ios, xcode6, interface-builder, uipickerview

Is there any way to get the picker view in Xcode 6 to appear as it was in Xcode 4?

[image: 3D Wheel]
<sub>(source: [timroadley.com](http://timroadley.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/RolePicker.jpg))</sub>

[image: Flat Picker]
<sub>(source: [developpez.com](http://codewithchris.developpez.com/tutoriels/ios/exemple-tutoriel-ios-7-uipickerview/images/1000000000000152000000FA7BDF9BF2.jpg))</sub>

Thank you.

Comment: It's a feature of iOS 7 and later. It has nothing to do with the version of Xcode. And no, under iOS 7 and later you get the new look. Write your own custom picker if you want something like the old look (which users will hate since it won't match the newest iOS).

Comment: Do you mean by adding a background image?

Comment: i doubt it and you most importantly *should* not! There is good reasons it is designed as it is: it fits the ui style of iOS, why would you want an ugly black&blueish picker?

Comment: @luk2302: While I do appreciate the lesson in aesthetics, that doesn't really answer my question, does it.

Comment: Solved: apparently it was nothing more than a background image to begin with.

Comment: @iSofia could you please post as answer whatever you did to solve the above issue.

Comment: Sure, Lion! Like I said in the earlier comment, I just added a background image to the picker view control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, the newer versions of iOS spot the plain-white picker view with just a focus window. To improve the aesthetics, to a look somewhat similar to the earlier versions, simply add a suitable background image to the control.